# Photos app in ios 7.1 simulator not working

Tags: xcode5.1

i clean installed os x Yosemite yesterday and installed xcode 6. but unfortunately my old project require ios 7.1 so i delete xcode 6 and installed xcode 5.1.1. everything seems to be working fine but when i click on Photos app in simulator, it stuck on white screen as screen shows first when lunching app. I tried to reset content & setting but no luck. then i uninstall xcode completely including `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode, ~/Library/Developer, ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` directory and files manually and reinstalled xcode 5.1.1 but problem with Photos app not solved.

So please help me to solve this problem. do i missed something?, do i have to completely erase and reinstall mac to get working again or there is a compatibility problem in Yosemite with xcode 5.1.1.
Also i know that i can install 7.1 simulator in xcode 6 but it will require some extra changes in my code as xcode 6. ios 8 simulator in xcode 6 has no problem like this. (sorry i am new here and i can't attach screenshot because don't have 10 points)

error was :

```
Oct 30 11:34:38 CS02-MAC.local SpringBoard[4941] <Warning>: BBServer: data provider "com.apple.mobileslideshow" has been unresponsive for 60 seconds.
Oct 30 11:34:46 CS02-MAC.local assetsd[4998] <Notice>: PLMigrationLog <t:0xb016de0> Failed to fetch path to uuid mappings 21 unable to open database file
Oct 30 11:34:46 CS02-MAC.local assetsd[4998] <Notice>: PLMigrationLog <t:0xb016de0> No store file to move aside at "/Users/css/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Media/PhotoData/Photos.sqlite"
Oct 30 11:34:46 CS02-MAC.local assetsd[4998] <Notice>: PLMigrationLog <t:0xb016de0> Failed to open store /Users/css/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Media/PhotoData/Photos.sqlite with options {
        NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey = NSFileProtectionNone;
        NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption = 1;
        NSSQLitePersistWALOption = 1;
        NSSQLitePragmasOption =     {
            "journal_mode" = WAL;
        };
    }.  Requires new rebuilt database (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)")
Oct 30 11:34:46 CS02-MAC.local assetsd[4998] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.
I open the log by Debug->Open system log and investigate the problem and came to know that the file 'Photos.sqlite' was not found. I manually copied that file from another mac to '▸ Users ▸ [username] ▸ Library ▸ Application Support ▸ iPhone Simulator ▸ 7.1 ▸ Media ▸ PhotoData'.
After that Photos app working properly.
Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to publish the answer, I had the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Another, easier method (especially if you don't have the file elsewhere), is that you can also just create a blank file called Photos.sqlite and place it in ▸ Users ▸ [username] ▸ Library ▸ Application Support ▸ iPhone Simulator ▸ 7.1 ▸ Media ▸ PhotoData

(eg: run this from the terminal:)
touch "/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Media/PhotoData/Photos.sqlite"

That worked for me.